# Can't make posts requests in Electron using axios (makes only get requests)

Tags: javascript, http, https, electron, axios

I am building a simple app using Electron and Axios to make http requests. But every time I try to make a post request to my server it only makes a get request as I see it in Chrome Devtools. I can't understand what is happening here.

*On the server side I have a Laravel backend app that accepts only POST requests.*

[image]

index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="axios.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            axios.post('https://www.example.com/api/users/', {
                firstName: 'Fred',
                lastName: 'Flintstone'
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 530,
    height: 520,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    },
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
  win.setAlwaysOnTop(true)

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the headers

Application/json